# Multiplication of two number in 2's complement

Tags: number-systems

Suppose that we have two n bit, binary numbers in 2'th complement. If we multiply them the result needs less than 2n bits except in one state result needs 2n bit.

What is that state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is when you multiply the smallest negative number by itself. For example, with $2$ bits: $10\times 10=0100$ (i.e. $(-2)\times(-2)=4$) and you really need the leading zero to express the fact that the result is positive.